# Splitting file path in batch using for loop and variable substitution

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, cmd, substitution

I have searched around for quite a while without any luck in getting my script working. I feel like I'm pretty close, but need a little help. I am attempting to use a FOR loop to recursively scan "srcdir" (set at the beginning of my script), then once the loop returns files/paths (%%f), then I can substitute part of the file path with something else (eg; C:\rootpath\src for C:\rootpath\des).

I am able to do something just like this by using a script like this one:

```
set subdir=C:\rootpath\src
set subdir=%subdir:src=des%
echo %subdir%
```

However, what makes this difficult is that the root path of my "srcdir" may change (eg; C:\roothpath) and everything recursively after the "srcdir" may change (eg. anything after folder "src" in C:\rootpath\src). The only constant paths the folder src and the folder des (located in the same directory where I am running my batch file from).

So, by using the same technique in the previous example, I want to use a FOR loop to recursively find the full path of the files in "srcdir" (%%f) and substitute the folder "src" with the folder "des" in the path string. Therefore, I am trying to set "%%f" as a variable (subdir) and replace the folders using variable substitution.

Here is my current non-working script:

```
set srcdir=C:\rootpath\src
for /r "%srcdir%" %%f in (*.txt) do (
set subdir=%%f
set subdir=%subdir:src=des%
echo %subdir%
)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You'll need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) as soon as you set and read variables within a code block like a `for` loop...

Comment: so I should use 'Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion' before the for loop starts?

Comment: Yes, this enables it; to actually use it, you need to expand variables like `!variable!` rather than `%variable%`; this is also true for the sub-string substitution syntax...

Comment: I appreciate your help so far. I have also seen this before, but don't know if I understand how to use it in context. How exactly would I use this in the context of my script so that (%%F) can be set within the variable "a"?

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36313781) below, which demonstrates usage of delayed expansion in your script... which variable `a` are you talking about??

Comment: You might also want to see what `FORFILES /?` can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) since you are assigning and reading variables within a block of code like a `for` loop:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "srcdir=C:\rootpath\src"
for /R "%srcdir%" %%F in ("*.txt") do (
    set "subdir=%%~fF"
    set "subdir=!subdir:\src\=\des\!"
    echo(!subdir!
)
endlocal
```

The `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` command enables delayed expansion; it also localises the environment, meaning that changes to environment variables are available only before `endlocal` is executed or the batch file is terminated.

To actually use delayed expansion, you need to replace the percent signs by exclamation marks, so `%subdir%` becomes `!subdir!`.

Comment: Thank you so much. That makes much more sense. I was able to get the script working and understand delayed expansion better. :)

Comment: It appears though that the variable does not survive after "endlocal" , so is there a way to do this and keep the variable for use later in the batch file?

Comment: Yes, there is, just replace `endlocal` by the line `endlocal & set "subdir=%subdir%"` (though this fails when the value contains `!`)…